# Simple Flask jQuery AJAX

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to get the logic of using jQuery AJAX and Flask, however I am not coming right. I have been following tutorials [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/jquery-flask-tutorial/) and [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/), but no resolution. To get the  logic - I simply want to input dates in two separate fields, and return those dates to the same page in a normal `<p>` tag. My suspicion is a problem in the server receiving the dates. Submitting the relative form does not return anything to `#result`

HTML FORM

```
<form>
    <input name="StartDate" id="StartDate" type="date" class="form-control"></div>
    <input name="EndDate" id="EndDate" type="date" class="form-control"></div>
    <a href="#" id="generate"><button class='btn btn-info'>Generate</button></a>
</form>
<p id=result></p>
```

jQuery - located at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, after importing jQuery itself.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#generate').bind('click', function () {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/generate_report', {
                StartDate: $('input[name="StartDate"]').val(),
                EndDate: $('input[name="EndDate"]').val()
            }, function (data) {
               $("#result").text(data.result);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Flask Server - I have imported relevant dependencies

```
@app.route('/generate_report', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def generate_report():

    start_date = request.args.get('StartDate', 0, type=str)
    end_date = request.args.get('EndDate', 0, type=str)
    
    return jsonify(result=start_date + "-" + end_date)
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot from the browser debugger. from the network tab and console, tab to see if there is any error or not. also, we can see together what is your request and response and then we can solve it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the button to send the form, an anchor within the form does not make sense.

I would advise you to use the ["submit"](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event
of the form, although the "click" event of the button would also work. The [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) function bypasses the standard behavior of the form, so that you can send the form yourself using [`getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). To serialize the form data, I use the [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
function which converts all form data into a conforming string. Thus the data is sent as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

The variable `$SCRIPT_ROOT` is not used by me in this example because it is
basically empty under localhost and is not absolutely necessary.

```
<form name="my-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="start-date">Start</label>
    <input type="date" name="start-date" id="start-date" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="end-date">End</label>
    <input type="date" name="end-date" id="end-date" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button>
</form>
<p id=result></p>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("form[name='my-form']").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.getJSON("/generate_report", formData, function(data) {
          $("#result").text(data.result);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

The result of `request.args.get` is by default of type `str`.
If the form field is empty, `get` always returns `None`. A possible `KeyError` due to a missing value is bypassed.

```
@app.route('/generate_report')
def generate_report():
    start_date = request.args.get('start-date')
    end_date = request.args.get('end-date')
    return jsonify(result=f'{start_date} - {end_date}')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this in the new week and revert!

Comment: This is a pin-point perfect answer, thank you - I will mark it. I only now see the unnecessity of `$SCRIPT_ROOT`, should have payed closer attention to that.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you know of any sources/answers to use the same logic for a file upload? I have asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151680/jquery-ajax-file-upload-getting-the-actual-file-from-input but no luck