# jQuery AJAX file upload - getting the actual file from input

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a simple file upload to Flask server using jQuery AJAX. My jQuery is relatively shocking, and so I think I am struggling at the part of collecting the file from the input field for my AJAX call.

HTML

```
<form name="csvimportdataform" id="csvimportdataform">
    <input id="csvfile" name="csvfile" type="file" class="form-control-file">
    <button id="importdata" name="importdata" class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Proceed</button>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("form[name='csvimportdataform']").submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var form_data = $('#csvfile').prop('files')[0];

    $.getJSON("/AJAX_call", form_data, function (data) {
        //code to do stuff with the response

    });

});
```

When I check the console for errors when submitting the form, I get `TypeError: Illegal invocation`...`at HTMLFormElement.v.handle` - let me know if more is needed here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not sure what you want to do with the data on the server side and how the server's response should be, I used the standard [example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) for uploading files.

```
@app.route('/upload-csv', methods=['POST'])
def upload_csv():
    if 'csvfile' in request.files:
        file = request.files['csvfile']
        if file.filename == '':
            return '', 400
        dest = os.path.join(
            current_app.instance_path,
            current_app.config.get('UPLOAD_FOLDER', 'files'),
            secure_filename(file.filename)
        )
        file.save(dest)
        return '', 201
    return '', 400
```

To transfer the data of the form via Ajax you can use an object of the type [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData).
The data is sent with the POST method of a form as "multipart/form-data".

There are many functions within jquery that enable the sending and querying of data. The [`$.ajax(...)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) variant is the most versatile.

```
<form name="csvimportdataform" id="csvimportdataform">
    <input 
        type="file" 
        name="csvfile" 
        id="csvfile" 
        class="form-control-file"
    />
    <button
        type="submit"
        name="importdata" 
        id="importdata" 
        class="btn btn-info" 
    >Proceed</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("form[name='csvimportdataform']").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/upload-csv',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. You've helped me so much I cannot thank you enough. Just to clarify `$.getJSON` does not work for the sole reason being we dealing with a file input? Thanks again

Comment: @KyleWalden ```getJSON``` uses HTTP GET and is therefore not suitable for this purpose. You can transfer forms via GET, but this is relatively rare. In a GET request, the data are appended to the url and in POST they find their place in the request body. Which method you use depends largely on the amount and visibility for third parties.